# Merge every other column

Tags: awk, gsub

Trying to merge every other tab delim column starting from `$3` in

```
NC_044998.1     3757    ref     ref     ref     ref     ref     ref     ref     ref     ref     dev
```

So that output is

```
NC_044998.1     3757    refref     refref     refref     refref     refdev
```

using

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = "\t"} {for (i=3; i<=12; i+=2) {gsub(/\t/, "", $i)1;} print $0};' input
```

but output same as input

Comment: If you use `\t` as column separator, a column can no longer contain the separator itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu awk`, you can do this using regex:

```
awk -F '\t' -v beg=2 '{
   s=""
   for (i=1; i<=beg; ++i)
      s = s $i FS;
   print s gensub( /\t+(\S+\t*)/, "\\1", "g", substr($0, length(s)+1) )
}' file
```

```
NC_044998.1  3757   refref  refref  refref  refref  refdev
```

PS: You can put any other column position as `beg` parameter in this awk command

Answer (score 1):

With **GNU** awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} { for (i=0; i<5; i++){$(i+3)=$(i*2+3) $(i*2+4)} NF=7; print }' input
```

Output:

```
NC_044998.1     3757    refref  refref  refref  refref  refdev
```

What is happening here?

- Column 3 gets the content of column 3 and 4.
- Column 4 gets the content of column 5 and 6.
- Column 5 gets the content of column 7 and 8.
- Column 6 gets the content of column 9 and 10.
- Column 7 gets the content of column 11 and 12.
- The output of the columns is limited to the first 7 columns (`NF=7`).

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, **NF**, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Thank you! In reality my file has 53 columns and I wanna starting merging every other from column 32. So it would become awk 'BEGIN {FS = "\t"} { for (i=0; i<53; i++){$(i+32)=$(i*2+3) $(i*2+4)}; print }', right?

Comment: I assume: `awk -v start=32 -v end=53 '{FS=OFS="\t"} { for (i=0; i<end-start; i++){$(i+start)=$(i*2+start) $(i*2+start+1) } NF=(end-start-1)/2+start; print }' input`